# Different price for different countries

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

I saw there are apps that have a different price on different iTunes stores (according to location). How do they do that? I didn't see any place in iTunes Connect that enables that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't have different price for different country.
The only thing is when you choose a tier, it is not the same value according to the country currency.

e.g. : tier 1 = $.99 (US) = .79€ (Europe) = 230 Yens (Japan)

If you really want to have different prices, you must have the same app multiple times.

```
e.g. :
Application 1 : only distributed on US country (at any tier)
Application 1 bis : distributed on other country than US (at any other tier)
```

Application 1 and Application 1 bis is exactly the same application, but with a little difference, e.g. language (if you do not localize your app)

Comment: And apple are o.k. with me doing that? (creating two apps which are identical). I can also put the same up more than once in order to have  more than 100 chars keywords (and this surely doesn't sound something apple will be o.k. with).

Comment: I guess, they will do... They won't see it, they have so many app, I'm sure they don't spend time comparing all your Apps together...

Answer (score 5):

It is possible now! Now you can set different prices based on territories for the same IAP package.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/WorkingWithYourProductsStatus.html

Comment: Note that different territory pricing is only available for auto-renewable subscriptions, at least from what I saw.

Answer (score 2):

Meanwhile, there is an SDK [(Mage)](https://github.com/getmageio/mage-ios-sdk) available, which is also working for consumables and non-consumables (unlike with iTunes Connect where it only works with subscriptions). Additionally, they automatically take care of optimizing prices according to the markets. You can find the documentation in the repository (there is an android as well as react-native SDK available too).

If you are using the option in iTunes Connect to change subscription prices according to locations be aware, that:

1. If you reduce your prices: all existing customers will also profit from that immediately.
2. If you increase your prices: all existing customers will be warned and get the opportunity to cancel.

---

For full disclosure, I'm one of the Co-Founders. We faced the same problems like you multiple times. This is why we created Mage.

Answer (score 1):

Release them as separate apps, then set the target countries so they do not overlap.

Comment: Apple is very strict on duplicate apps now, I'm pretty sure they wouldn't allow this. If anyone knows different would love to hear

Comment: There are lots of companies which have different versions of similar apps for different countries.