# One App. Different Territories. Multiple In App Purchase Price

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'd first like to clarify that i am a product development manager and not on the app code development side, but I do have a question about in-app purchase from my perspective that I'm hoping for help on

I/we are developing an application to release in three different territories with three different ios in-app purchase prices (one price per territory and each price in its own currency).

As a product owner I'm told this is possible, but I don't know where the logic lies. In iTunes connect (seemingly) I am only able to select a certain tier of pricing and these aren't prices that we want to use. The apple app store matrix isn't offering pricing we want to use.

Can anyone tell me if we can release one IOS app in itunes connect, with three diffferent IA prices, set by us, each in its own territory

thank-you

Comment: You have been misinformed. In-app purchases have a single price tier assigned. This results in different prices in local currency as defined for that tier but you cannot have different price tiers for different regions.  You could define different in-app purchase objects and try and determine the region in which the user is using your app (based on the current device locale) and only offer the appropriate in-app purchases but this is far from foolproof.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I'm a little confused. You're second point negates the first. It sounds like defining different objects means we could geo locate the user and then offer a different price point based on where you are. Does that mean we could offer a price point not available in the matrix?

Comment: Looking at Netflix Australia they offer a price point which is not currently in the matrix.

Comment: I can only assume that Netflix have made some special arrangement with Apple get get the $11.99 price point.  You can attempt to geolocate the user and offer a subset of your defined in-app to them in your app interface,  but the price points still need to be in the matrix (unless you have Netflix volumes and you can convince Apple otherwise...)

Answer (score 0):

It's a possible duplicates of [Different price for different countries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172653/different-price-for-different-countries)

I think you have been misguided over IAP.